# Managing translations in a dynamic environment

Tags: localization, internationalization

I'm developing an application which requires translations for all of its text fields. The backend is built using Django, and the front end is done using Java for native android, and swift for native iOS.

Where would it be better to handle the translations - Front end or Back end? I have seen several answers but it all depends on the developers approach. From my side the less load we put on the server, the better.

As a method, I can mainly think of two ways:

1. Create a reference table for the strings requiring translations, and another table containing all the translation. However I believe that this method will be a bit heavy on the backend and will add additional overhead that can be bypassed. We can use several techniques to reduce the workload however it remains unnecessary.
2. Create a language pack (JSON/XML file) which will contain all the strings and corresponding translations. On application startup, if the version of the language pack is the same, use the old one (no request to the backend), otherwise load the new pack (one time call) and save it locally. This way all the translations will be done from the front end.

What do you think is the best approach, and is there anything better?